# cout statement change program semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, cout

I have the following piece of code, which is part of a class, whose details hopefully are not important for answering that question. I don't want an exact solution to my problem, but only an explanation, how the behavior, I'm going to describe, can occur.

```
    Character operator+(Character c) {
        std::vector<float> resDensity(density);
        float l;
        float dh;
        for (int i = 0; i < domains.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c.domains.size(); j++) {
                l = (domains[i].intersection(c.domains[j])).length();
                //std::cout << l;
                dh = c.density[j] * l / domains[i].length();
                resDensity[i] += dh;
            }
        }
        std::vector<Domain> h(domains);
        return Character(h, resDensity);
    }
```

You probably noticed the commented `cout` statement. Due to a numeric bug in my program, I followed the falsy value until I detected the variable `l`. So I printed it to the console and found out, that the value is exactly the value I need, and also the program works just fine and the bug simply vanished. Uncommenting it, again, leads to the undesired misbehavior.

The `Character` class contains the fields `domains` and `density`, both `vector`s...

The `length` and `intersection` method:

```
    float length() {
        float res;
        for (int i = 0; i < is.size(); i++) {
            res += is[i].b - is[i].a;
        }
        return res;
    }

    Domain intersection(Domain d) {
        std::vector<Interval> hi;
        for (auto i = is.begin(); i != is.end(); i++) {
            for (auto j = d.is.begin(); j != d.is.end(); j++) {
                hi.push_back(i->intersection(*j));
            }
        }
        Domain hhh(hi);
        return hhh;
    }
```

I compiled the code with `g++ --std=c++11 ...`

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20131219 (prerelease)
```

Comment: Looks pretty commented to me...

Comment: There is probably some undefined behavior occurring somewhere in your program, manifesting itself as this "heisenbug".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `-ffloat-store` does not change the outcome, but it is interesting, that the precision, with or without this option, is only 4 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `length()` function the `res` variable is uninitialized:

```
    float res;
    for (int i = 0; i < is.size(); i++) {
        res += is[i].b - is[i].a;   // <-- uses an uninitialized res
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

How is `length()` calculated on `Domain`? `hhh` is a local variable that you are returning, so a copy will be made. If `length()` depends on something that is not copied then you will see strange behaviour. What if you just change `intersection()` to return a float or create a different method called `intersectionLength()` which returns a float - do you still get the heisenbug?

Comment: the `length` method just uses properties of the copied object

Comment: @spiehr - of `hi`? In which case what does the constructor of `Domain` look like and how is `std::vector<Interval>` stored?

Comment: and you had the right feeling! Wouldn't have posted without you